# How to use spread operator for objects in Typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching some data from Firestore:

```
getDocs(colRef).then(
  (val) => {
    const tempArray: Array<categoryFetchData> = val.docs.map((d) => {
      const categoryData: {categoryName: string, color: string, createdAt: Timestamp} = d.data(); 
      return {id: d.id, ...categoryData}
      }
  }
)
```

`d.data()` has a return type of `DocumentData`, but will return

`{categoryName: "someString", color: "someColor", createdAt: Timestamp.now()}` from the collection that I am fetching.

The return type of my function is `Array<categoryFetchData>`

```
type categoryFetchData = {
    categoryName: string, color: string, createdAt: Timestamp, id: string
}
```

Currently I get the error:

`Type 'DocumentData' is missing the following properties from type '{ categoryName: string; color: string; createdAt: Timestamp; }': categoryName, color, createdAt`

When trying to spread `d.data()` into the return value.

This can be fixed by using:

```
type ExpenseCategoryStruct = {categoryName: string; color: string; createdAt: Timestamp;};
const categoryData = d.data() as ExpenseCategoryStruct;
```

Is there a better way to do this without having to create a new variable for `d.data()` and using `as`

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```js
type CategoryFetchData = { categoryName: string, color: string, createdAt: Timestamp, id: string }

getDocs(colRef).then(snapshot => {
    const tempArray = snapshot.docs.map(d => { return {...d.data(), id: d.id} as CategoryFetchData })
})
```

You may get error because one of documents do not have same fields like type you created.

Comment: This gives me an error at `tempArray` `Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'categoryFetchData': categoryName, color, createdAt`

Comment: @FergusJohnson are you sure all of your documents have fields like you wrote in you type?

Comment: @FergusJohnson Your type has field `id: string` or not?

Comment: @FergusJohnson Dude you cannot assign any other random fields to your type.

Comment: `ExpenseCategoryStruct` has `{categoryName: string; color: string; createdAt: Timestamp;}`

`categoryFetchData` has `{categoryName: string, color: string, createdAt: Timestamp, id: string}`

Comment: @FergusJohnson Types names starts with large letter, not small.